# Rails table joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, html-table, arel

I'm trying to figure out how to do a table join in one of my models.

There are points, questions, and users.

**point.rb**

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :question
end
```

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :points
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

In my **Points controller** I am doing this:

```
def index
    @points = Point.all
    @user_points = Point.where('user_id' => current_user)
end
```

And in my **points/index** view:

```
    <% @user_points.each do |user_point| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= current_user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user_point.question_id %></td>
    <td><%= user_point.correct_answer %></td>
    <td><%= user_point.user_answer %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I need to access the name of each question in the questions table (I have the question id available in my view. I'm a n00b to rails, and can't figure out how to this with the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Rails Guides, especially these two:

1. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
2. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

I think you should be able to set this in your **model**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :points, :through => :questions
end
```

in your **controller** say `@user_points = current_user.points`

in your **view**. This should already work with your current code!

```
<% @user_points.each do |user_point| %>
    <td><%= user_point.question.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Simon - working through this now...through should be :through in the response (if you could edit your response for others benefit that would be great), and it works!!! :) I am digesting how this all happens through the links you provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you read my previous answer ignore it. I misread your question. This should work.

In your view:

```
<% user_points.questions.each do |question| %>
  ...Do whatever...
<% end %>
```